# How to use multiple REGEX on one variable?

Tags: php, regex

I have a function which is containing multiple REGEX. Here is my function:

```
function generate($str) {
  $str = preg_replace(/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/, "<b>$1</b>", $str);
  $str = preg_replace(/__(.*?)__/, "<u>$1</u>", $str);
  $str = preg_replace(/\*(.*?)\*/, "<i>$1</i>", $str);
  $str = preg_replace(/--(.*?)--/, "<del>$1</del>", $str);
  $str = preg_replace(/`(.*?)`/, "<code>$1</code>", $str);
  return $str;
}
```

Now I want to know is this ^ the standard way? Overwriting several times on one variable? Is there any better approach?

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php You can do everything in one call

Comment: @Rizier123 Do you mean something like what the followed answer said?

Comment: Yes, read the manual there is everything documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) says that the first two parameters can be arrays or strings. If they are arrays, each match in the first array will be replaced by the corresponding string in the second array. E.g.:

```
function generate($str) {
  return preg_replace(
    array(
      '/\*\*(.*?)\*\*/',
      '/__(.*?)__/',
      '/\*(.*?)\*/',
      '/--(.*?)--/',
      '/`(.*?)`/'
    ),
    array(
      "<b>$1</b>",
      "<u>$1</u>",
      "<i>$1</i>",
      "<del>$1</del>",
      "<code>$1</code>"
    ),
    $str
  );
}
```

Comment: Good solution. `return preg_replace(...)` should be enough here.

Comment: Yes, that's a good simplification. I edited the answer to reflect this.